# What is the correct form

Tags: phrase-requests

> "*Strange by no means*, the bus is actually faster than the train"

or

> "*Strange as it may seem*, the bus is actually faster than the train."

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take a look at http://english.stackexchange.com/tour. We'd like to hear what research you've done, and perhaps which alternative you think correct and why.

Answer (score 1):

"*Strange as it may seem*" is the correct form.  I don't think "*strange by no means*" is a common expression.